# Filter posts by meta query?

Tags: meta-query

I made custom post type and used a meta query …

For this link:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=itinerary&action=-1&m=0&ipt_country=0&ipt_city=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2
```

… I want this this meta query to apply:

```
'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'ipt_country',
                'value' => $qv['ipt_country']
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'ipt_city',
                'value' => $qv['ipt_city']
            )               
        ),
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little more convoluted, but main queries for admin can be modified roughly in a same way as front end. You would need to:

1. hook into `pre_get_posts`
2. check for `is_admin()`
3. check for `is_main_query()`
4. check for specific page you want to adjust
5. apply your adjustments to the query if all matches